# Best way to UNION ALL several tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union-all

I have several tables with monthly user data, they all have the same schema.
I want to merge all the data into a single table in BigQuery so my guess is that UNION ALL will work. So I'm doing the following.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  `Cyclistic.202105`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM 
  `Cyclistic.202106`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM
  `Cyclistic.202107`
#Repeat the same for 202108, 202109 and so on...
```

So far this works but I have dozens of tables that need to be merged, is there a faster/better way to do this?

Comment: The best way is not to have a table for each month, but a single table with a date column. Otherwise, I guess you're stuck with unioning. Perhaps you can create a `view`, but you'd have to make sure it's up-to-date

Comment: Maybe generate the query dynamically? From a maintenance point of view it is easier as you don't have to edit SQL directly. Performance wise it is similar to what you are doing now. Otherwise, If you can then the suggestion by @HoneyBadger is the way I would prefer.